# Como fazer condição no iReport acaso não exista um dos valores

Tags: ireport, jasper

Tenho uma expressão do tipo 
`$F{nome_pai} + " e de " + $F{nome_mae}` numa declaração só que por vezes não tem a o nome do pai ou da mãe na base de dados e fica o texto `casado, filho de e de ...`

Como não fazer aparecer o `e de` caso não exista um dos nomes.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
${nome_pai}.equals("")?(${nome_mae}.equals("")?"":${nome_mae}):
${nome_pai}+(${nome_mae}.equals("")?"":" e de "+${nome_mae})
```

**Explicando...**

**A primeira parte:** Se o nome do pai for vazio, vamos verificar se o nome da mãe é vazio ou não, caso seja vazio ambos os nomes como pode ver na condição não escreverá esta parte, caso tenha só  nome da mãe respectivamente escrevera o nome da mãe.

**A segunda parte:** Se o nome do pai não for vazio, escrevemos respectivamente o nome do pai, e verificamos se tem o nome da mãe, caso não tenha não escrevemos nada, caso contrario adicionamos `" e de "` concatenamos com o nome da mãe.